# Full SSL security

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I've installed a SSL certificate on my website http://core-electronics.com.au/eCommerce

When I visit it in Chrome it says there are unsecured items on the site. What have I overlooked?

Comment: Hard to tell, I get a 403 trying to look.

Comment: Just open up the Chrome developer tools, check in the resources tab what came from an HTTP request, and fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the Chrome developer tools and select the Network tab. Refresh your page, and click the first resource on the list. The right pane will transform into a tabbed view, with the selected tab being "Headers", and the first information displayed, Request URL.

Now, cycle through these until you find resources that were loaded from an http connection instead of https. You can use the down key to select the next resource.

I found 7 of them within a few minutes. You should try it.

Comment: Or just go to the console, where it'll tell you insecure URLs were blocked.

Comment: Thanks a lot zneak, it's now full SSL certified!

Answer (score 4):

You cannot have content links pointing to non-SSL URL's. Everything must point to HTTPS URL's. Images, style sheets, scripts, everything.

If you have any embedded plugins, such as the Twitter tweet button, those should use protocol-less URL's.

Open the Firefox content dialog or Chrome developer tools and review all your links. You should be able to spot the insecure content it pretty easily.

Comment: Right, so there must be some absolute links to http content then?

Comment: Yes, or you might have a non-SSL <basepath/> and relative URL's. If you have any embedded plugins, those should use protocol-less URL's.

Comment: Thanks a lot jimp, it's now full SSL certified!